# Find out the location or page where the Font was not embedded in PDf using Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-parsing

I am using `Itext` library to manipulate my PDF.

I am using this example http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#616-listusedfonts.java to find out the fonts which are not embedded in PDF.

Does the library provide any option to check where exactly was the font not embedded in the PDF?

Comment: The sample only inspects the pages and the form xobjects referenced from them and outputs information on the fonts provided in these resources. If you need to pinpoint where exactly which kind of font is used, you have to use a different mechanism and use the parser package classes with a custom render listener, i.e. one built by you to act on text drawing operations while such a not embedded font is used..

Comment: @mkl: Thanx for your reply.Can you please provide some more info on that,cos I am not a Java guy, Does Itext provides such a package? Any helpful links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sample referenced by the OP](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-16#616-listusedfonts.java) only inspects the pages and the form xobjects referenced from them, and it outputs information on the fonts provided in the resources of these entities.

If one needs to pinpoint where *exactly* which kind of font is used, one has to use a different mechanism, the parser package classes with a custom render listener. This listener then can act on text drawing operations while such a not embedded font is used.

### The parser framework

To find out where some resource actually is used on a page, you have to parse the page content stream and check the PDF instructions therein.

iText helps you in doing so by providing a parser framework which reads the content stream and pre-analyzes it. The results of this first analysis are forwarded to a render listener you provide.

You use the parser framework like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
for (int page = from; page <= to; page++)
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    RenderListener renderListener = YOUR_RENDER_LISTENER_IMPLEMENTATION;
    parser.processContent(page, renderListener);
    // after the page has been processed, probably 
    // some render listener related post-processing
}
```

For e.g. text extraction, you usually use the render listener implementations `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` or `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` (which come with iText) and after the page has been processed, you retrieve the `String` of text from the strategy it has extracted from the events from the page.

### The render listener to customize

Render listeners in iText 5 have to implement the interface `RenderListener`:

```
public interface RenderListener {
    /**
     * Called when a new text block is beginning (i.e. BT)
     */
    public void beginTextBlock();

    /**
     * Called when text should be rendered
     * @param renderInfo information specifying what to render
     */
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo);

    /**
     * Called when a text block has ended (i.e. ET)
     */
    public void endTextBlock();

    /**
     * Called when image should be rendered
     * @param renderInfo information specifying what to render
     */
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo);
}
```

or `ExtRenderListener` which declares some additional listener methods.

A render listener for your task, i.e. a render listener to find where exactly a given font is used to draw text, only needs to implement `renderText` non-trivially, e.g. like this:

```
public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    DocumentFont documentFont = renderInfo.getFont();
    PdfDictionary font = documentFont.getFontDictionary();
    // Check the font dictionary like in your example code
    if (font FULFILLS SOME CRITERIA)
    {
        // The text
        String text = renderInfo.getText();
        // is rendered on the current page on the base line
        LineSegment baseline = renderInfo.getBaseline();
        // using a font fulfilling the given criteria
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer..I have been trying to implement it but a little lost. What exactly should go into this line `RenderListener renderListener = YOUR_RENDER_LISTENER_IMPLEMENTATION;`. This is how I am creating an instance of my renderlistener      `MyFontRenderListener listener = new MyFontRenderListener();`.  I am creating the instance of the `renderlistener` in file called `extractfonts.java`. So inside the for loop, when I use `parser.processContent(i, listener);`, how will I call the  `renderText()` function which is inside my `MyFontRenderListener .java` file?

Comment: @Abhinav *"What exactly should go into this line `RenderListener renderListener = YOUR_RENDER_LISTENER_IMPLEMENTATION;`. This is how I am creating an instance of my renderlistener `MyFontRenderListener listener = new MyFontRenderListener()`"* - As `MyFontRenderListener` implements `RenderListener`, you can simply write `MyFontRenderListener renderListener = new MyFontRenderListener()` there.

Comment: @Abhinav *"So inside the for loop, when I use `parser.processContent(i, listener);`, how will I call the `renderText()` function which is inside my `MyFontRenderListener` .java file?"* - As the `listener` is an instance of your `MyFontRenderListener` class, your `renderText()` implementation will be called by `parser.processContent(i, listener);`.

Comment: I am getting this error `Cast Argument 'listener' to 'E' in this line `parser.processContent(i, listener);`. Any ideas on how it can be solved?

Comment: @Abhinav Does your `MyFontRenderListener` implement `RenderListener`?  Do you use at least Java 5? If the answer to either question is "No", that is the problem. Otherwise edit your question with enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: my bad...dint implement RenderListener, that was the error,thanks. In the `renderText` function, are `getText();` and `getBaseline();` user defined functions? Cos I am recieving the error to create the functions. If its user defined, how should I be implementing it?

Comment: Sorry, that was kind of pseudo code there. Those methods are methods of the `renderInfo` parameter, see my edited question.

Comment: I got what I needed, you even helped me wid your `MarginFinder` class some time back...thank you  :)